# Retrieving data from HDD (WD Green)

Tags: hard-drive, nas, hard-drive-recovery

I am getting crazy retrieving data from an old hard disk.
I had a WD My World II NAS with 2 x 1 TB HDD WD Green hard drives RAID 1.

Now I am moving to a different configuration and I want to retrive the data. I am using a MacBook Pro with Big Sur.
Starting the NAS is not effective because it works 1 time over 10 so I decided to read the data directly from the HDD.
I bought a USB connector and when connecting the HDD to the system it tells me that the HD cannot be mounted.

I tried with diskutil list and obtained

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                 Linux_RAID                         2.0 GB     disk2s1
   2:                 Linux_RAID                         263.2 MB   disk2s2
   3:                 Linux_RAID                         1.0 GB     disk2s3
   4:                 Linux_RAID                         996.9 GB   disk2s4
```

I also tried to read the disk using the fuse-xfs solution linked here :
https://eekayonline.medium.com/recovering-data-from-a-xfs-diskdrive-on-mac-os-catalina-da687b19bf17

I tried all the sectors but the console tells me that

```
root@MBP ~ # fuse-xfs /dev/disk2s4 -- /Volumes/TestMount
cache_node_purge: refcount was 1, not zero (node=0x7fc1e1d05170)
libxfs: cannot read root inode (990)
probe: /dev/disk2s4 filesystem failed to initialize
probe: Aborting.
```

And that

```
root@MBP ~ # fuse-xfs /dev/disk2 -- /Volumes/TestMount
No XFS signature on /dev/disk2
```

I am trying to install VirtualBox with a Linux distro on it to see if it possible to mount the drive.
Any advices or solutions ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It seems like either both disks were damaged, or the controller used a
proprietary RAID format.

The RAID controller for the NAS was probably hardware, so
I suggest getting the data via the NAS, even if you have to start it many times.
Otherwise, you may need to use professional services.

Once (if) the data is recovered, I don't advise trusting these two disks without
backup. Important data should never be used without backup.